# Sequence that maps to arbitrary positive real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do you construct a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ such that

$$s = \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{f_n(x)}$$

for all $s > 0$?

I know it's possible to this with a different sequence

$$s = \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$$

where $x = \log(s)$.

The motivation is from proofs on radius of convergence which rely on the definition of the radius

$$r = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{f_n(x)}}$$

and out of curiosity I tried to construct a function similar to that for $e^x$ that could map to any $s = 1/r$ but couldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_n(x)=x^n$, then $\sqrt[n]{f_n(x)}=x$ and you are there.

Comment: Oh wow, I missed the obvious by about a mile. Thanks!